# how do i get a container from ibm object storage using a local python code

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, object-storage

i'm writing a python code to get a list of containers from my ibm object storage that i have created.

i have installed swiftclient,keystoneclient as well as cerftifi pyopenssl packages.

```
import swiftclient.client as swiftclient

auth_url = "<auth_url>"
project_id = "<Project_id>"
user_id = "<user_id>"
region_name = "<region_name>"
password = "<password>"
conn = swiftclient.Connection(
        key = password,
        authurl = auth_url,
        auth_version = '3',
        os_options = {"project_id": project_id,
                      "user_id": user_id,
                      "region_name": region_name})



for container in conn.get_account():
    print(container['name'])
```

i wanted to get the name of the container 
instead it is giving me an error like access forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Please open a support ticket in the IBM Cloud console to take a look at your account.